# Сферы применения машинного обучения

Tags: машинное-обучение

В последнее время часто сталкиваюсь с термином "Машинное обучение". Мой вопрос состоит из двух частей. Во-первых, для чего используется машинное обучение, если можно с наиболее интересными примерами. И второе, более волнующее меня, какие предварительные знания нужны для того, чтобы начать обучаться самостоятельно курсу "Машинное обучение"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) достаточно хорошо описывает практические сферы применения машинного обучения:

- Распознавание речи
- Распознавание жестов
- Распознавание рукописного ввода
- Распознавание образов
- Техническая диагностика
- Медицинская диагностика
- Прогнозирование временных рядов
- Биоинформатика
- Обнаружение мошенничества
- Обнаружение спама
- Категоризация документов
- Биржевой технический анализ
- Финансовый надзор
- Кредитный скоринг
- Прогнозирование ухода клиентов
- Хемоинформатика
- Обучение ранжированию в информационном поиске

> Какие предварительные знания нужны для того, чтобы начать обучаться
>   самостоятельно курсу "Машинное обучение"

по-моему субъективному мнению достаточно следующего:

- хорошей мотивации (это, по-моему,  главный пункт)
- понимания основ линейной алгебры. Хорошие курсы по машинному обучению (например [курс от проф. Andrew Ng](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning)) позволяют вспомнить необходимые моменты и плавно ведут вас от самого простого к более сложному.
- для практического применения было бынеплохо овладеть базовыми навыками кодирования на одном из языков программирования. Для `Machine Learning` наиболее популярным является `Python`. Также распространены `Java` и `R`.

Comment: MaxU-при всем уважении,разделение  задач  регрессии и классификации не совсем корректно.И то и другое-попытка сначала по известным образцам  построить модель, а затем с ее помощью предсказать значение некоторого ранее неизвестного объекта. Разница в типе данных:для регрессии -  данные измерены в числовой шкале, для классификации - дихатомические либо номинальные данные.  В машинном обучении все это рассматривается как задачи "обучения с учителем".А кластеризация задача кардинально другого типа -  "обучения без учителя",-надо взять некоторые объекты, и разбить на (заранее неизвестные) классы.

Comment: @passant, согласен - это спорный момент. Сначала стоило было упомянуть об обучении с учителем и без, а уже потом о регрессии и классификации. Убрал этот абзац... ;)

Comment: Спасибо за комментарии. Еще возник вопрос по мотивации. В чем она может заключаться для обучающегося? Могли бы вы выделить в порядке убывания, хотя бы 5 пунктов. Спасибо.

Comment: @EmilGariff, это вам [сюда](http://kak-bog.ru/teoriya-motivacii-maslou). Кстати, чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа можно [проголосовать за ответ (для этого необходимо иметь минимум 15 репутационных балов)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400/348814) и/или [принять ответ как правильный](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/348814) ;)